# Why are there differences of compiled c++17 lambdas between GCC and clang?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang, c++17

This reproduces on GCC 7.1 and clang 4.0., also on both snapshots on July 30, 2017.

Example 1: Calling lambdas other than in return statement, both compilers behave differently.

```
int main()
{
    auto sum = [](auto ... a) { return (... + a); };

    auto value1{sum(5,5)};   // Having optimization disabled -O0,
                             // GCC treats this line as if constexpr is there,
                             // clang doesn't.

    constexpr auto value2{sum(1,2,3,4)};  // Both treat this line as constexpr like expected.

                            // As a result, in GCC, no trace of lambdas in the executable,
                            // and only one lambda in clang.

    return value1 + value2;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/NPPKSR) @godbolt

Example 2 and 3: Calling lambdas in return statement, both compilers behave the same way: runtime evaluation/no constexpr.

```
int main()
{
    auto sum = [](auto ... a) { return (... + a); };

    return sum(5,5) + sum(1,2,3,4);   // Both compilers generate 2 lambdas like expected.

}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/hEL63e) @godbolt

```
int main()
{
    constexpr auto sum = [](auto ... a) { return (... + a); };

    return sum(5,5) + sum(1,2,3,4);   // Both compilers generate 2 lambdas like expected.

}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/4qzwCA) @godbolt

---

Does the standard body let this happen between compilers? Why?

Comment: Turn on optimizations and compare again.

Comment: It's not clear why this is a problem. Is there any observable (i.e. by executing the code, not inspecting the assembly) difference between them?

Comment: The standard defines the language, it doesn't describe how compilers must be implemented. As long as the behavior is consistent with the rules of the language, it is fine even if the two compilers differ in their output.

Comment: A compiler is allowed to notice that an expression is constant and evaluate it at compile time. There is no need to generate code for 5+5 when it can be replaced with 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Calling lambdas other than in return statement, both compilers behave differently.

They may output different assembly, but they have the exact same behavior. This is what the Standard guarantees, nothing else. So in that regard, both are correct, as they both return `20`.

`constexpr` expressions don't have to be evaluated at compile time if it is possible. There is nothing prohibiting implementations to call `add` instead of optimizing it out in the following example:

```
constexpr int add(int lhs, int rhs) {
    return lhs + rhs;
}

int main() {
    return add(4, 5);
}
```

They *can*, but that doesn't mean that they *must*. The Standard tries to give implementations as much freedom as possible when compiling, to allow heavy optimizations for example, which is in part the reason why undefined behavior and things like *ill-formed; no diagnostics required* exist (correct me if I'm wrong).

Do note that compiling with `-O3` results in both compilers returning `20` in your three examples, so no difference there.

Comment: Can I put it this way: "non-constexpr caller doesn't guarantee constexpr-ness or runtime-ness of constexpr callee at all" ?

Comment: @sandthorn Exactly, only the opposite holds.

Comment: So this isn't specifically related to c++17 lambda, which is happened to be constexpr by default, but this is the behavioral nature of constexpr keyword since c++11?

Comment: @sandthorn Yes. Compilers have always had the liberty of optimizing expressions out that they could calculate at compile time (as far as I can remember).

Comment: c++11 [Live](https://godbolt.org/g/uWTNvC) @godbolt. This example acts just complement for the 15-char length restriction! Thank you.